# ReactJs - how to keep only one "active" section at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, components

I'm having issues with finding a solution or correct direction for my problem. At the moment once you click on -> className="List-section", it will show the information in -> className="Paragraph-container", but there are 4 sections of it and **I want to only allow one section to be open at a time**. At the moment I can open all of them and be displayed.
**If it helps, here's the link to the prototype(and how the flow should be):** https://www.figma.com/proto/ooya7hVTx4BvdwQQFPXZcj/CCT-Lab-task?node-id=5%3A711&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=5%3A509

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Parent Component

```
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      title: "Build test task",
      items: [
        "Create repositor",
        "Implement designs",
        "Implement functionality",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "Submit your test task",
      items: [
        "Open email client",
        "Sent link information to careers@cornercasetech.com",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "Participate in tech interview",
      items: ["Talk with HR", "Talk with Tech team"],
    },
    {
      title: "Reciece anster",
      items: ["Receive answers", "Start your IT career"],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>CCT Lab Process</h1>
      </header>
      <div className="App-content">
      {data.map((dataObject, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index} listData={dataObject} listNumber={index + 1} />
      ))}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component

```
function ListItem({ listNumber, listData }) {
  const [isShownOne, setIsShownOne] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="List">
      <div className="List-section" onClick={() => setIsShownOne(!isShownOne)}
      >
        <div className="Section-item">{listNumber}</div>
        <p className="Section-title">{listData.title}</p>
      </div>
      {isShownOne && (
        <div className="List-paragraph">
          {listData.items.map((paragraphItem, index) => (
            <div className="Paragraph-container" key={index}>
              <CheckedIcon  />
              <p className="Paragraph-item">{paragraphItem}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

BTW, tried to google all possible options but was not able to find a solution. Some suggest checking id in the Parent component and passing the logic to the Child. Feeling a bit lost at the moment!

Comment: If you search on here for "react accordion" you'll probably find a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lift the state up into the parent component, and change it to a number. The value represents which child (if any) is open. Then pass down a prop to each child.

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(-1);

  // ...
  {data.map((dataObject, index) => (
    <ListItem 
      key={index} 
      listData={dataObject} 
      listNumber={index + 1} 
      open={open === index}
      setOpen={setOpen}
    />
  ))}
}

function ListItem({ listNumber, listData, open, setOpen }) {
  // ...
  <div 
    className="List-section" 
    onClick={() => {
      setOpen(prev => {
        if (prev === listNumber - 1) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return listNumber - 1;
        }
      })
    }}
  >
  // ...
  {open && (
    <div className="List-paragraph">
      {listData.items.map((paragraphItem, index) => (
        <div className="Paragraph-container" key={index}>
          <CheckedIcon  />
          <p className="Paragraph-item">{paragraphItem}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
  </div>
}
```

You may be interested in this article: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: It worked,  I have been trying to find the solution for 7h... Thank you so much, that was a simple and elegant solution!!!